# Flutter simple inheritance concept

Tags: inheritance, flutter

newbie here.
In swift you just easily inheritate other class by :

```
class Train: Vehicle {
    override func makeNoise() {
        print("Choo Choo")
    }
}
```

I want to inherite from material widget, let say from GestureDetector :

```
class Button extends GestureDetector{

  @override
  get onTap => super.onTap;
}
```

I have a class to access audio in single statement. I want to put an audio of button, so when onTap, it will play the audio. So, how can i put 
Audio.playButton() in Button class onTap?

Comment: You're not supposed to inherit widgets. Use composition instead

Comment: Hi @RémiRousselet, could you give me some example of composition?